# MongoDB error on update method during multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, mongodb-query, apache-storm

i'm working with Apache Storm and i want to write on a MongoDB database but, sometimes, it throws an exception of

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "updatedExisting" : false , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: TesiMarco.UserPostNew_Hampshire index: _id_ dup key: { : \"mainelyinspired\" }" , "code" : 11000}
```

while using parallelism option. In particular my bolt was executing:

```
    public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String user=input.getString(0);
    DBObject query=new BasicDBObject("_id",user);
    DBObject toUpdate=new BasicDBObject("$inc",new BasicDBObject("numeroPost",1));
    collection.update(query,toUpdate,true,false);
}
```

but it finds duplicated error on key. How can i execute this part multithreading?